# Does anyone know about Hera Panchami?

Tags: vishnu, gods, festivals, lakshmi

Fight Between Lord Jagannath And Laxmi at the time of Rath Yatra; known as Hera Panchami. Does anyone know about Hera Panchami mythology and the reason to celebrate it?

Answer (score 1):

The rituals of Hera Panchami as an important function of Srimandira finds mention in Skanda Purana. According to the history of the Temple, this "utsav" started during the time of Maharaja Kapilendra Deb. Before his reign, the Hera Panchami function was being observed in a symbolic way with recitation of Mantras.As stated in Madala Panji, Raja Kapilendra Deb substituted this practice with the introduction of an idol of Mahalaxmi mode of gold and making the celebration more realistic.

**According to Legends** : Lord Jagannath along with his siblings leaves for a vacation to his aunt’s place and his consort Mahalaxmi is left behind in the main temple. While leaving he had promised that he would return back the next day, but time passed by and he never came back, nor did he give any information. After the 5th Day, Goddess Laxmi became impatient and hence decided to visit the Gundicha temple to see if everything was ok.

At night of the 5th day the representative idol of Goddess Mahalaxmi (known as Subarna Mahalaxmi) is made to leave for the Gundicha temple in a beautifully decorated palanquin via Bada Danda (the Grand Road) in a colorful procession in pomp and splendor, accompanied by her servitors, to meet Lord Jagannath and to ask Him why he had not returned yet. The people & servitors who are part of the procession of Goddess Mahalaxmi sing the Hera Panchami song. The Hera Panchami song expresses Goddess Mahalaxmi’s anger towards Her husband. After knowing that Goddess Mahalaxmi is coming to meet him with anger, Lord Jagannath asks his servitors to quickly lock the door of Gundicha Temple. After having a stealthy look at her Lord, she returns to the temple, damaging a part of Jagannath’s chariot in anger and disgust. This is what the crowd witnesses with profuse excitement.

Comment: This is copy-pasted from [bolg](https://rgyan.com/blogs/hera-panchami-the-grand-fight-between-lord-jagannath-and-laxmi/). Plagiarism not allowed, blogs are not allowed. This clearly sounds overt promotion or advertising of a blog.